# Why when the "cut" event fires, the input field is not empty yet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener, contenteditable

The problem is that when I cut the text and the program reaches the "cut" event listener it never passes the if statement because inputField.innerHTML still is reading the previous value.

How could I overcome this behavior?

I have not idea how to google this, so I thought having it analyzed and explained by a human being would be a viable solution.

Thanks!

```js
const inputField = document.querySelector(".input-field");

inputField.addEventListener("cut", () => {

console.log("getSelection: " + document.getSelection());
console.log("innerHTML: " + inputField.innerHTML);
  if (inputField.innerHTML === "") {
    console.log("I am here");
  }
});
```

```css
.input-field {
  min-height:35px;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin:5px;
  border: 2px solid #e6e6e6;      
}

[contenteditable="true"]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  pointer-events: none;
  display: block; /* For Firefox */
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field" placeholder="Tell me something..." contentEditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: The cut event triggers before the cut has actually taken place visually.  Could you compare the clipboard data (document.getSelection()) to your element’s content?

Comment: Is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more reliable solution is to compare the empty string with the [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) not `innerHTML` as the last contains an `<br>` element anyway, that's why the condition is not matching. Also, the event and DOM update does not run in the same microtask, so the updated content should be retrieved asynchronously, with [queueMicrotask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/queueMicrotask), or [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for example:

```js
const inputField = document.querySelector(".input-field");

inputField.addEventListener("cut", () => {
  console.log(inputField.innerHTML);
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    if (/^\n?$/.test(inputField.textContent)) {
      console.log("I am here");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.input-field {
  min-height:35px;
  width: 40%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin:5px;
  border: 2px solid #e6e6e6;      
}

[contenteditable="true"]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  pointer-events: none;
  display: block; /* For Firefox */
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field" placeholder="Tell me something..." contentEditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Still does not pass the if statement as per my test.

Comment: Seems that you are using Chrome, while for me it was working in Firefox, so seems that in Chrome we should wait a whole frame, fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works this way and yes, I am using chrome and chrome mobile.